# How to Convert datetime.datetime.now() to Number

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

Script:

```
datetime.datetime.now()
```

will give

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 9, 19, 55, 45, 938208)
```

And I want to convert like:

```
201949195545938208
```

I need this to create unique folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`strftime()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm):

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%z"))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
20190409193226
```

**EDIT**:

Use `%f`, if you want to tag along the milliseconds as well.

Comment: Did you need that to be an integer or string?

Comment: @piRSquared, I need in String

Comment: I hate when I reach the daily limit of recieving the reputation sdfkjsdfhskdfhbsdfkjsfsdfsdfsdfsdf

Comment: @DirtyBit First World SO Problems (-;

Comment: @piRSquared any workaround for that? except leaving the desk? 8-)

Comment: Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) and scroll to the bottom.  You'll see the number of times you've achieved 200 rep via upvotes alone.  Mine is at 279.  When you get to 150 you get the [legendary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary) badge, which has only been awarded 264 times.